# php form select options array from mysql variable

Tags: php, arrays, forms, variables

Hopefully a simple one.

I am using a drop down on a form as follows:

```
// A sample product array
$products = array("Mobile", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Camera");
```

this works fine but rather than define the list I was hoping to populate the options using a variable populated from Mysql, Here is what I have

```
// A sample product array
$products = array<?php echo $customoption1data;>;
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

The data in the table is formatted as "Mobile", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Camera"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why not store the data as individual rows? and then do a select to get your array.

Comment: You're now echoing php code inside a php snippet, that won't work. You should use some MySQL query requesting the values from your database, then fetch the result of this query using e.g. mysqli and use that as your array. Like andre3wap says, it is indeed cleaner to store the data as individual rows.

Comment: unfortunately  I can't change the format of the database to add a extra rows. spotted the echoing and corrected that but still no joy

Comment: use `$products = explode(',', $customoption1data)`. Then remove the `"` from each entry